# How to pass an array of objects to nodejs and send the array to a document in mongo

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I used to send objects to nodejs server using req.body.object
But now I want to send an array of objects to a mongo document but req.body.array doesn't seem to work

In my front end, I've managed to save an array named myList but when I req.body.myList in the app.post route, I get amazing errors like " Unexpected token n in JSON at position 4"

```
app.post("/bills/:id", function(req, res) {

    var list = req.body.myList
    console.log(list)

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the body of the request is already the array, you just have to take it with

```
var list = req.body;
```